# S3 access private bucket files

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have gone through all the existing questions doesn't seems to be fullfill my requirements.

I have a `S3 private bucket` with 10000 files, Privately accessing via Nodejs server to display in my angular application atleast 25 per page.

I found multiple solutions those seems Inefficient to my thoughts.

- Generate pre-signed urls for files.
- Pulls the image via the Nodejs API from S3

To display 10 or more need to generate signed Url's each time which is a time consuming process. And pulling image via api using s3.getObject method gives me a Buffer data converting it to a Base64 is hard to handle at the client side and fetching each consumes time this too.

Are these any solutions out there which I'm not aware of and how this can be implemented without affecting user experience.

PS: My Bucket is `private` not public

Comment: What is your goal? To protect the content to only authorized users? Or you just want to deliver images from a private bucket to your website users?

Comment: Why do you say generating signed URLs is a time consuming process?  Even with thousands to do (which you don't need, since you only have 25 per page), it's on the order of milliseconds per URL, and you can do it in parallel.

Comment: @JohnHanley  To protect the content to only authorized users

Comment: The only "secure" solution is to generate presigned URLs. I would also employ CloudFront with presigned urls to deliver content.

Comment: @JohnHanley ok thanks for your suggestion. I think I'm not using it properly then, need to look more into presigned URL.

Comment: Consider ceskamx answer using signed cookies. I forgot about this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried **signed cookies**?

I think this may help you by just considering **AWS CloudFront** and signed the cookie one time to let the client access any file(s) directly after that.

[There is some reference.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Also, CloudFront will give you more benefits such as optimize the access speed, attach SSL Certificates to your S3 buckets, and more.

"Sorry for my English"

Comment: Thanks for the reference and letting me know about signed cookies